# Instantiating multiple instances of one object in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a simple addition program using Java and I wanted to know if it's possible to make multiple instances of an object work:

```
public class test {
    class Number { 
        public Number(double d, double e) {
    }
    public double number1;
    public double number2;
}

Number numSet1 = new Number(15.0, 30.0);
Number numSet2 = new Number(20.0, 30.0);

private void setNum(double n1, double n2) {
    number1 = n1;
    number2 = n2;
}

private static double getSum(double n1, double n2) {
    return number1 + number2;
}
```

I want the output to be this:
`45.0`
`50.0`
respectively.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does this even compile? If you are asking "can I make more than one instance of my classes", then: yes, sure, that's why we have classes in the first place.

Comment: Terminology clarification: an object and an instance are basically the same thing; each object is an instance of a class. So it doesn't make sense to say "multiple instances of an object." I think what you may be asking about is multiple instances of a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely have multiple instances of a **class** *(not object, the object is the instance itself)*

Here is your code in a more simple form:

```
public class Addition {
    private double operand1;
    private double operand2;

    public Addition(double o1, double o2) {
        operand1 = o1;
        operand2 = o2;
    }

    public  double getSum() {
        return operand1 + operand2;
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double res1 = new Addition(15.0, 30.0).getSum(); // Addition instance 1
        double res2 = new Addition(20.0, 30.0).getSum(); // Addition instance 2

        System.out.println("Result1: " + res1);    // Result1: 45.0
        System.out.println("Result2: " + res2);    // Result2: 50.0
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
public class test {
    class Number { 
        public Number(double d, double e) {
          number1 = d;
          number2 = e;
    }
    public double number1;
    public double number2;
}

private void setNum(double n1, double n2) {
    number1 = n1;
    number2 = n2;
}

private double getSum() {
    return number1 + number2;
}
```

// test  Call from main?

```
Number numSet1 = new Number(15.0, 30.0);
Number numSet2 = new Number(20.0, 30.0);

result = numSet1.getSum ();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I can't get it to compile.

Comment: What is the compile message (really important to read these).  Try letting me see your `main` method

Comment: Well, this is what I have: http://pastebin.com/V3swyNGK
Not sure if I'm doing the main method right, but the getSum method is underlined red.

Comment: I did. I tried doing the result = numSet1.getSum();
Still doesn't work.